# Eclipse Kepler local javadoc confguration

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, eclipse-kepler

I need some help with setting local javadoc in Eclipse Kepler, since it seems the behavior has changed from Juno to Kepler.

I have set the url for the installed jdk as follows

```
file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/docs/api
```

In Juno clicking on a class name and pressing F1 the class javadoc page opens. The address from properties is

```
file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html?noframes=true#FileInputStream(java.lang.String)
```

Opening the same workspace using Kepler and following the same procedure, the javadoc page does not open, instead showing a "page cannot be displayed" message. The address retrieved  from properties in this case is

```
res://ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff_webOC.htm#file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/docs/api/noframes=true
```

The documentation pages for the particular configuration have not changed between Juno and Kepler, therefore I would expect no difference in behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be an answer, and considering the installation is plain vanilla it may indeed be a bug.

As a workaround, in order to solve this problem, I created an IIS virtual directory with the jdk's api directory, registered the url for the Eclipse javadocs and now it works.